# Adding another one-to-many relation between two tables that already have one

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I have two tables, `Accounts` and `Reservations`. There is a one-to-many relationship between them (one Account can have many Reservations), so the Reservations table has an `AccountId` column.

```cs
public class Account 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    ...
    [JsonIgnore] 
    public List<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; } = new List<Reservation>();
}

public class Reservation 
{
    ...
    public Guid AccountId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore] 
    public Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework figures this out by itself, I don't have anything specific about this realtion in `OnModelCreating()`.

Now I need to add another relation like that, when a "parent" account creates a reservation on behalf of a "regular" account. So Reservations needs a `ParentAccountId` column that also points to Accounts. The original relation needs to stay as is.

I added the following in the Reservation class:

```cs
public Guid? ParentAccountId { get; set; }

[JsonIgnore] 
public Account? ParentAccount { get; set; }
```

Now EF is no longer able to reslove the relations on its own, I get the following error when I try to rebuild the database:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Account.Reservations' of type 'List'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

How can I configure this correctly?

Comment: Simply add a table that defines each Account type and add a one-to-many relationship between the Type and Account. That way you don't have to muck up your db with json ignores/not mapped entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Fluent API to "explain" your intent:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
    .HasMany(a => a.Reservations)
    .WithOne(r => r.Account);
modelBuilder.Entity<Reservation>()
    .HasOne(r => r.ParentAccount)
    .WithMany();
```

Note that you can't map multiple relations to the same collection property (hence the original error), if you want it exposed you will need to declare a new one:

```
public class Account 
{
    // ...

    [JsonIgnore] 
    public List<Reservation> ReservationsAsParent { get; set; } = new List<Reservation>();
}
```

And mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
    .HasMany(a => a.Reservations)
    .WithOne(r => r.Account);        
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
    .HasMany(a => a.ReservationsAsParent)
    .WithOne(r => r.ParentAccount);
```